# Не получается загрузить unity editor через unity hub

Tags: unity-hub

Хотел переустановить unity editor версии 2020.3.1f1 с поддержкой андроид разработки и предустановленными jdk sdk ndk . Удалил старый editor  ,  и добавил в закачки новую версию с поддержкой андроид билда . В итоге загрузка множество раз прерывалась , выдавала ошибку **something went wrong installing unity** .
Есть ли способы решения этой ошибки?

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй все снести и заново начать качать. Плюс, дополнительно установи Android Studio на свою машину и установи из неё Android API последней версии (нужно будет для сборки). Если не выходит, попробуй найти видео на YouTube (желательно свежие) и повтори все действия.